# Не видит [TestFixtureSetUp] NUnit Framework. .NET Core. C#

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, .net-core, nunit

Помогите разрешить следующую ситуацию:

[image: Ошибка TestFixtureSetUp]

Есть и директива `using NUnit.Framework;`, и установлены все необходимые пакеты NuGet: Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk, NUnit, NUnit3TestAdapter.

Comment: Может нужен пакет `NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, что с NUnit 3.0 для моего случая(вызов метода инициализации чего-либо один раз перед всеми тестами) нужно использовать атрибут **[OneTimeSetUp]**.

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-and-TearDown-Changes